# How to access the body of the post request in express?

Tags: node.js, express, post, request

I have been trying to send a post request to the node and the data I have passed through the body of the post request is not showing in the request.body .How can I access the body of the post request?

This is the code I am using for receiving the post request

```
   const express = require('express');

    const request = require('request');

    const app = express();

    app.use(express.json());

    app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
    const locationName = req.body;
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({requestBody: req.body});
    } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
    }
    });

    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
```

when I try to make a post request from postman It shows as

```
{
     {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`express` by default don't handle the request body, you must install package for it and integrate it in your `app`, to allow your endpoints to read body data.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser);
```

Additionally you can check your request headers to include `Content-Type` header, with value `application/json`

Comment: Hi, this is outdated; read [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine.
When you are making a post request from postman you need to select row data JSON formate in the request body